# Modifing archive query affects show post count function

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to modify the archive query of archive page with this function hooked to `pre_get_posts` action hook.

```
// Load our function when hook is set
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_limit_posts' );
function rc_modify_query_limit_posts( $query ) {

// Check if on frontend and main query is modified
if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() ) {

    $query->set('posts_per_page', '9');

}
```

This is working perfectly, but somehow messes up my function for displaying current posts displayed"

```
function archive_post_count() {

    global $wp_query;
    $showing = '';

    if ( $wp_query->found_posts > 1 ) {

        $page_number = is_paged() ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
        $current_max = ( get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) * ( $page_number - 1 ) ) + $wp_query->post_count;
        $current_min = $current_max - $wp_query->post_count + 1;

        $range   = ( $current_min == $current_max ) ? strval( $current_min ) : $current_min . '-' . $current_max;
        $total   = $wp_query->found_posts;

        $showing = 'Shown ' . $range . ' from ' . $total . ' posts ';

    }

    echo $showing;

}
```

Currently I have 11 posts and on first page everything works OK. But when I hit page 2 "Shown 11-12 from 11 posts" message is shown. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` does not explicitely changes the value in the db of `posts_per_page`, this value stays constant to the value set in the back end under the readings settings. `pre_get_posts` only changes this value before the SQL query is build in `WP_Query` right before the main query runs.

If you need to get the exact ( more specific ) amount of posts per page set for a specific page when using `pre_get_posts`, access the query vars which will hold the new value set by `pre_get_posts`. (***NOTE:*** `query_posts` breaks the main query object, so if you use `query_posts` somewhere on the page, this will also fail as you will get an incorrect value. This is **ONE BIG REASON** why you should never ever use `query_posts` Here is [an answer that explains this in detail.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/47733))

Instead of using

```
get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
```

use

```
$wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
```

Comment: Thank you, @Pieter Goosen! I've spotted this earlier after I reviewed my code again. For testing reasons, I changed the archive posts count in settings and also worked, but it impacts the whole blog. Thanks again!

Comment: @destructor glad it worked out for you. Enjoy :-)